# Php + Ajax Форма отправляется даже если данные не прошли валидацию

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
Есть форма, ajax-скрипт и обработчик. Юзер регистрируется, но Ajax сразу перенаправляет на страницу, даже если введены не полные данные, хотя ошибки подсвечивает

Обработчик:

<?php
require_once("classes/user.class.php");

session_start();
$userMail = $_POST['userMail'];
$userLogin = $_POST['userLogin'];
$userRealName = $_POST['userRealName'];
$userPass = $_POST['userPass'];
$userBDay = $_POST['userBDay'];
$inputCountry = $_POST['inputCountry'];

$duplicate_mail = $userAuth->checkUserMail($userMail);
$duplicate_login = $userAuth->checkUserlogin($userLogin);
if ($duplicate_mail == true || $duplicate_login == true) {
    echo json_encode(array("statusCode" => 201));
} else {
    $userExecute = $userAuth->registerUser($userMail, $userLogin, $userRealName, $userPass, date("Y-m-d", strtotime($userBDay)), $inputCountry);
    $_SESSION["login"]=$userLogin;
    $_SESSION["mail"]=$userMail;
    if(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && isset($_SESSION["mail"])){
        //header("Location: panel.php");
    }
    echo json_encode(array("statusCode" => 200));
}
?>

Форма:
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="sign-up-form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email:<br></label>
                <div class="input-group" id="divMail">
                    <input class="form-control" name="userMail" id="userMail" type="email"
                           placeholder="email" autofocus>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Login:<br></label>
                <div class="input-group" id="divLogin">
                    <input class="form-control" name="userLogin" id="userLogin" type="text"
                           placeholder="Login">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Real Name:<br></label>
                <div class="input-group" id="divName">
                    <input class="form-control" name="userRealName" id="userRealName" type="text"
                           placeholder="Real Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password:<br></label>
                <div class="input-group" id="divPass">
                    <input class="form-control" name="userPass" id="userPass" type="password"
                           placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Birth Date:<br></label>
                <div class="input-group" id="divBday">
                    <input class="form-control" name="userBDay" id="userBDay" type="date"
                           placeholder="Birthd Day">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="divCountry">
                <label>Country:<br></label>
                <select id="inputCountry" name="inputCountry" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected name="inputCountry" id="selectCountry" ></option>
                        <?php
                        foreach($countName as $k=>$v){
                            echo '<option>'.$v.'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1" required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1" >
                        <span style="text-align:center;" >Agree with terms and conditions</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" id="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться">
            <p class="form-message"></p>
            <div id="result"></div>
        </form>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sign-up-form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userMail = $('#userMail').val();
        var userLogin = $('#userLogin').val();
        var userRealName = $('#userRealName').val();
        var userPass = $('#userPass').val();
        var userBDay = $('#userBDay').val();

        $(".error").remove();

        if (userMail.length < 1) {
            $('div.input-group#divMail').after('<p class="error" style="color: red; padding-top: 10px;">Write your email</p>');
        }
        if (userLogin.length < 4) {
            $('div.input-group#divLogin').after('<p class="error" style="color: red; padding-top: 10px;">Write your login</p>');
        }
        if (userRealName.length < 2) {
            $('div.input-group#divName').after('<p class="error" style="color: red; padding-top: 10px;">Write your name</p>');
        }
        if (userPass.length < 6) {
            $('div.input-group#divPass').after('<p class="error" style="color: red; padding-top: 10px;">Password must be at least 6 characters long</p>');
        }
        if (userBDay.length === 0) {
            $('div.input-group#divBday').after('<p class="error" style="color: red; padding-top: 10px;">Enter your date of birth</p>');
        }

        var serializedData = $("#sign-up-form").serialize();
        var request;
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "handler.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData,
        });

        request.done(function (jqXHR, textStatus, response) {
            $("#result").html(response);
            window.location = "panel.php";
            console.log("complete");
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#result").html('There is some error while submit');
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: " +
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ...
    if (userBDay.length === 0) {
        $('div.input-group#divBday').after('<p class="error" style="color: red; padding-top: 10px;">Enter your date of birth</p>');
    }

    if ($(".error").length)
        return;

    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло. И ещё такой вопрос, в скрипте идёт только валидация на пустоту и длину, в обработчике ещё есть два метода класса проверяющие дубликацию в базе мыла и логина. Как можно их прикрепить на ajax?

Comment: @pon89aa Да, лучше - отдельный вопрос.